# Optaplanner returning a non optimal solution

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am trying to use Optaplanner to solve a problem where I have to send quantities of SKUs to a warehouse with a limited space, given a certain demand for each SKU.

My hard score is that the total quantity sent (over all SKUs) should be less than the space of the warehouse.
An my hard score is to maximize the sales (ventes in my code bellow).

Planning Entity :

```
@PlanningEntity
public class deploiement {

    private String Agence;
    private int capacityagence;
    
    @PlanningId
    private String SKU;
    private int prix;
    private int prevision;
    
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "DeploiementRange")
    private Integer Deploiement;
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "DeploiementRange")
    public CountableValueRange<Integer> getTransportedRange() {
    return ValueRangeFactory.createIntValueRange(0, prevision +1);
    }
    
    @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = varlistener.class,
            sources = {@PlanningVariableReference(entityClass=deploiement.class ,variableName = "Deploiement")})
    private Integer ventes;
... (constructor + getters and setters)
```

Variable listener :

```
    if(deploiment.getDeploiement()!=null) {
        int ventes =Math.min(deploiment.getDeploiement(),deploiment.getPrevision())*deploiment.getPrix();
        
        scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(deploiment, "ventes");
        deploiment.setVentes(ventes);
        scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(deploiment, "ventes");
        }
```

Constraint Provider :

```
public class Contraintes implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] {

                 maxCapacity(constraintFactory), 
                 maxsales(constraintFactory),
                 
         };
     }
    
    
     private Constraint maxCapacity(ConstraintFactory cf) {
         return cf.forEach(deploiement.class)
                 .groupBy(deploiement::getAgence, ConstraintCollectors.sum(deploiement::getDeploiement))
                 .join(deploiement.class)
                 .filter((agence, totaldep, dep) -> totaldep > dep.getCapacityagence())
                 .penalize("Maximum capacite agence" ,HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD ,(agence, totaldep, dep) -> totaldep - dep.getCapacityagence());
     }
     
     private Constraint maxsales(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
            return constraintFactory.forEach(deploiement.class)

                    .reward("max Sales Day ", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT ,deploiement::getVentes);
        }
    
}
```

Main method :

```
public class Mainmethod {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        SolverFactory<planingsolution> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(new SolverConfig()
                .withSolutionClass(planingsolution.class)
                .withEntityClasses(deploiement.class)
                .withConstraintProviderClass(Contraintes.class)
                .withTerminationSpentLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(10)));
        
    
        planingsolution problem = inputdata();
        
        Solver<planingsolution> solver=solverFactory.buildSolver();
        
        planingsolution solution = solver.solve(problem);

        // display results
        
         System.out.println("solution: " + "\n" + "\n" + "score: " + solution.getScore());
        
         print(solution);

    }
    
    public static planingsolution inputdata() {
    
        String Agence="Agence1";
        int CapacitéAgence = 20;
        
        String SKU1 = "SKU1";
        int PrevisionsParJoursku1 = 10;     
        int PrixSku1= 1;
        
        String SKU2 = "SKU2";
        int PrevisionsParJoursku2 = 30;     
        int PrixSku2= 2;
        
        
        List<deploiement> deploimentlist = new ArrayList<>();
                
        deploimentlist.add(new deploiement(Agence, CapacitéAgence, SKU1, PrixSku1, PrevisionsParJoursku1));
        
        deploimentlist.add(new deploiement(Agence, CapacitéAgence, SKU2, PrixSku2, PrevisionsParJoursku2)); 
        
    
    
        return new planingsolution(deploimentlist);
        
    }
    
    
public static void print(planingsolution solution) {
        
        List<deploiement> deploimentlist = solution.getDeplist();
        
        
        
        System.out.println("Agence" + " |   " + "capacité Agence" + "   |   " + 
        "SKU" + "   |   " + "previsions" + "    |   " + "Prix SKU" + "  |   "  
         +  "Deploiement" +"    |   " + "Ventes" + "\n");
        
        for(deploiement dep : deploimentlist) {
            
            System.out.println(dep.getAgence() + "  |   " + dep.getCapacityagence() + " |   " + 
                    dep.getSKU() + "    |   " + dep.getPrevision() + "  |   " + dep.getPrix() + "   |   "  
                     +  dep.getDeploiement() +" |   " + dep.getVentes() + "\n");
        }
        
    }

}
```

So the problem I am facing is that the solver try to stratify demand of SKU1 first then goes to SKU2, even though SKU2 is more expensive (which will result in higher sales). So in my exemple above, instead of giving the total Capacity of 20 to SKU2 (which gives a total sales of 40). It gives 10 to SKU1 and 10 to SKU2 (which is a total sales of 30).
I noticed that if I switch the order in which I initialize "deploiementlist" (such as the first element is that of SKU2 then SKU1) I get the desired result, which means that the solver starts with the top of the list then works its way down, and not looking for an over all optimal solution.

Should I write my code differently ? Or is this how Optaplanner usually work ?

EDIT :

**Log when the solver works as it's expected :**

> 00:51:06.287 [main        ] INFO  Solving started: time spent (79),
> best score (-2init/0hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move
> thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0). 00:51:06.342 [main
> ] DEBUG     CH step (0), time spent (134), score (-1init/0hard/8soft),
> selected move count (11), picked move (domain.deploiement@2c0b4c83
> {null -> 8}). 00:51:06.363 [main        ] DEBUG     CH step (1), time
> spent (156), score (0hard/8soft), selected move count (31), picked
> move (domain.deploiement@4acb2510 {null -> 0}). 00:51:06.363 [main
> ] INFO  Construction Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (156), best
> score (0hard/8soft), score calculation speed (623/sec), step total
> (2). 00:51:06.383 [main        ] DEBUG     LS step (0), time spent
> (176), score (0hard/16soft), new best score (0hard/16soft),
> accepted/selected move count (1/1), picked move
> (domain.deploiement@760245e1 {8} <-> domain.deploiement@31ceba99 {0}).
> 00:51:06.386 [main        ] DEBUG     LS step (1), time spent (179),
> score (0hard/8soft),     best score (0hard/16soft), accepted/selected
> move count (1/2), picked move (domain.deploiement@31ceba99 {8} <->
> domain.deploiement@760245e1 {0}). 00:51:06.393 [main        ] DEBUG
> LS step (2), time spent (186), score (0hard/16soft),     best score
> (0hard/16soft), accepted/selected move count (1/6), picked move
> (domain.deploiement@31ceba99 {0} <-> domain.deploiement@760245e1 {8}).
> 00:51:06.398 [main        ] DEBUG     LS step (3), time spent (191),
> score (0hard/8soft),     best score (0hard/16soft), accepted/selected
> move count (1/4), picked move (domain.deploiement@760245e1 {0} <->
> domain.deploiement@31ceba99 {8}). 00:51:06.401 [main        ] DEBUG
> LS step (4), time spent (194), score (0hard/16soft),     best score
> (0hard/16soft), accepted/selected move count (1/2), picked move
> (domain.deploiement@760245e1 {8} <-> domain.deploiement@31ceba99 {0}).
> 00:51:06.406 [main        ] DEBUG     LS step (5), time spent (199),
> score (0hard/8soft),     best score (0hard/16soft), accepted/selected
> move count (1/3), picked move (domain.deploiement@760245e1 {0} <->
> domain.deploiement@31ceba99 {8}). 00:51:06.409 [main        ] DEBUG
> LS step (6), time spent (202), score (0hard/16soft),     best score
> (0hard/16soft), accepted/selected move count (1/1), picked move
> (domain.deploiement@31ceba99 {0} <-> domain.deploiement@760245e1 {8}).
> . . . 00:51:16.207 [main        ] INFO  Local Search phase (1) ended:
> time spent (10000), best score (0hard/16soft), score calculation speed
> (171781/sec), step total (415). 00:51:16.210 [main        ] INFO
> Solving ended: time spent (10001), best score (0hard/16soft), score
> calculation speed (168969/sec), phase total (2), environment mode
> (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE). solution:
>
> score: 0hard/16soft

**Log when it breaks :**

> 00:50:28.084 [main        ] INFO  Solving started: time spent (79),
> best score (-2init/0hard/0soft), environment mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move
> thread count (NONE), random (JDK with seed 0). 00:50:28.146 [main
> ] DEBUG     CH step (0), time spent (142), score
> (-1init/0hard/10soft), selected move count (11), picked move
> (domain.deploiement@2c0b4c83 {null -> 10}). 00:50:28.171 [main
> ] DEBUG     CH step (1), time spent (167), score (0hard/30soft),
> selected move count (31), picked move (domain.deploiement@4acb2510
> {null -> 10}). 00:50:28.172 [main        ] INFO  Construction
> Heuristic phase (0) ended: time spent (168), best score
> (0hard/30soft), score calculation speed (544/sec), step total (2).
> 00:50:38.004 [main        ] DEBUG     LS step (0), time spent (10000),
> score (0hard/29soft),     best score (0hard/30soft), accepted/selected
> move count (0/2249955), picked move (domain.deploiement@7569ea63 {10
> -> 9}). 00:50:38.006 [main        ] INFO  Local Search phase (1) ended: time spent (10002), best score (0hard/30soft), score
> calculation speed (229003/sec), step total (1). 00:50:38.008 [main
> ] INFO  Solving ended: time spent (10002), best score (0hard/30soft),
> score calculation speed (224955/sec), phase total (2), environment
> mode (REPRODUCIBLE), move thread count (NONE). solution: score:
> 0hard/30soft

Answer (score 0):

Although the order of insertion is significant as that is generally the order in which OptaPlanner will iterate over the facts and entities, it should have no impact on the quality of the solution.

What does have impact on solution quality is your constraints. In your case, there is no constraint to tell OptaPlanner that SKU1 is preferrable to SKU2, or vice versa. How is OptaPlanner supposed to know to prefer one or the other?

Ask yourself that question, and turn the answer into a constraint. If that answer is capacity multiplied by price, then there should be a constraint that takes it into account. I do not see one in your problem description.

In the absence of such information, OptaPlanner will treat all facts as equivalent in terms of solution quality, and therefore it will pick an arbitrary one. (In this case, one that was inserted earlier.)

Comment: The answer to that question is the sales (ventes), which are defined as such : ventes=Min(deploiement, prevision)*prix. Which represent the weight in my soft constraint :  private Constraint maxsales(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
            return constraintFactory.forEach(deploiement.class)

                    .reward("max Sales Day ", HardSoftScore.ONE_SOFT ,deploiement::getVentes);
        }  . Did I write the constraint right or is it wrong ? Because in my head, it should tell Optaplanner that SKU2 is more expensive than SKU1 which means it should chose to prioritize SKU2.

Comment: To add to this, when the capacity is 8, which is less than both SKUs previsions (10 and 20), which means there isn't enough capacity to fully satisfy the prevision of either SKUs, Optaplanner gives the correct answer, which is assigning 8 to SKU2 (which results in the highest sales of 8*2=16). So the problem arises only when the capacity is between 10 and 20 .

Comment: I suggest you write a test using `ConstraintVerifier` (see documentation) to verify that your constraints do what you think they do. Once you've made sure of that, enable `FULL_ASSERT` environment mode and check that there are no score corruptions. And once even that check passes, if the problem still persists, let's discuss further.

Comment: Okey , I will try that and get back at you. Thank you very much

Comment: I tested the constraints and they work as intended. I also enabled FULL_ASSERT, and I still get the same results, although I noticed that the log I get when the solution is not optimal is different from the cases when it is optimal (I did not understand the logs well, so I added them in my original post as an Edit, hoping you can help me see what's wrong).

Comment: Interesting. Your construction heuristics (CH) has a different result every time, which is where your issue starts. Given that (unlike local search) CH is a completely deterministic algorithm, I find it hard to explain why that would be the case. The order of encounter is actually important in CH, so if you're using something like a `HashMap` instead of `LinkedHashMap`, that may be why CH does something different every time. Still, that is only a symptom; your problem is that in some cases, solver doesn't give you good answers. More constraints and/or move move types may solve that problem.

Comment: I think I will have to find a way around it then. Thank you for your responsiveness.